# Sheets IFS function with multiple AND operators

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to do a sheets function to look for a few different strings AND also check if another column is at least a minimum number.. I tried a few different variations of using IF, AND and IFS functions but cant get it working with multiple AND operators in the logical conditions.. The sheets functions are kinda weird and I just started using them.. There's probably a better way but it's only like 3 strings so this is fine too but they all evaluate to TRUE when one condition is not true like row 2 and 3..

I may have misunderstood this function, I thought it was like the following and returned the first true condition?

IFS(logical op, value, logical op, value..)

Here's a link with test data (removed)

The function looks like this:

```
=IFS( A1 = "text" & B1 > 4, TRUE, A1 = "text2" & B1 > 4, TRUE, A1 = "text3" & B1 > 4, TRUE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AND()` function inside `IFS()`. Try-

```
=IFERROR(IFS(AND(A1="text",B1>4), TRUE,AND(A1="text2",B1>4),TRUE,AND(A1="text3",B1>4),TRUE),FALSE)
```

You can also use `MAP()` function to make it dynamic.

```
=MAP(A1:A3,B1:B3,LAMBDA(x,y,OR(x="text",x="text2",x="text3")*(y>4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked, swear I tried to use AND inside like that but I must have messed something else up too..  Appreciate the help. I don't like the syntax of these Sheets functions..

Comment: @nick You may use `MAP()` function to simplify it. Try my edited answer.

Comment: That is a nice solution, however the way I'm using it there's also multiple minimum numbers like ["text2", >3], ["text3", >6] and I'm hoping to keep it simple enough for others to edit the parameters without much knowledge..